# Drag PolygonOptions android

Tags: android, draggable, polygon

How to drag poly-options on google map.I have created rectangle with some  points. I want to drag lines when I touch the lines.when i drag the the marker the line should remain connected. Please recommend me for right approach. This is my code please check it and suggest me.

```
PolygonOptions rectOptions = new PolygonOptions()
.add(new LatLng(mLatitude - 0.0004, mLongitude + 0.0004),
 new LatLng(mLatitude + 0.0004, mLongitude + 0.0004),
 new LatLng(mLatitude + 0.0004, mLongitude - 0.0004), 
 new LatLng(mLatitude - 0.0004, mLongitude - 0.0004), 
 new LatLng(mLatitude - 0.0004, mLongitude + 0.0004));``
ectOptions.strokeColor(R.color.grey);
polygon = googleMap.addPolygon(rectOptions);
```

Comment: Like grid in  Pix4Dcapture application

Answer (score 0):

I suggest entering an invisible Marker on the middle of the polygon that is draggable.